# Is there a way to look behind and ignore a specific letter in Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I need some help with regular expression,
(Long story short I'm creating a grammar checker for the language 'Papiamento', a language spoken in the ABC islands (caribbean), and some words can be abbreviated and I'm not sure how to look behind and ignore a letter)

I have the word "come" (eat) and "eating" would be "comiendo". See how an 'i' was added between the 'm' and the 'e'? I'm trying to get my regular expression to still be able to recognize the word "come" with and without the suffix "iendo", an easy fix would be to add a non-capturing group (not necessarily, I just use non-capturing group for things I don't need it to capture.) and check for both individually `/com(?:iendo|e)?/`, but I'm dealing with over 16 thousand words, and it isn't efficient to add a regular expression for every single word individually.

My question is:
Is there a way to look behind and ignore the letter 'e'?

`/(come((?<=e)iendo))/`
but also ignore the 'e', this regular expression only checks for "come" and "comeiendo" (which is incorrect)

---

To be a little more clearer, I have a `string[]` with all of the words,
Lets use this array for example `{ "come", "bisti", "pasa" }`, they're all verbs at their infinitive form.
I want the regular expression to be able to detect it at its infinitive form and the form where the action is being done (gerund).
"come" is the verb at its infinitive form, and "comiendo" is the gerund.

in my regular expression i have it

```cs
string[] words = { "come", "bisti", "pasa" };
string pattern = $@"/({string.Join("|", words)})/";

// which is same as:
string pattern = @"/(come|bisti|pasa)/";
```

but it's only checking for the infinitive form, the gerund most of the times ends with "ando" or "iendo" depending on the last letter of the verb. But in this case, I only want to focus on "come" and "comiendo" because it's the only one that replaces the last letter (which is 'e') with "iendo", (other verbs just append "ndo" to the end).

so the only thing I can think of with regular expression is to look behind if the verb ends with 'e' then ignore the 'e', and check for the verb (without 'e') ("com"), plus the suffix ("iendo").

"come" => "com" + "iendo"

and this is as far as I can get

```cs
string[] words = { "come", "bisti", "pasa" };
string pattern = $@"/((?:{string.Join("|", words)})(?:(?<=e)iendo|(?<=a)ndo)?)/";

// which is same as
string pattern = @"/((?:come|bisti|pasa)(?:(?<=e)iendo|(?<=a)ndo)?)/";
```

but that regular expression only works for "comeiendo" and not "comiendo"

[image]

Comment: What is the exact suffix: _endo_ or _iendo_. Spoken languages are of class 0, not class 3 in Chomsky classification. Regex is capable of checking grammar more than complex than class 3 but less complex than class 2. Thus using regex for this is not the best approach. Theoretically. Practically can work under some circumstances. You should try to grab the problem from a linguistic point of view (I am not a linguist, but have some knowledge). I am asking about the exact suffix, because if the _i_ is not inserted, but the _ee_ is transformed into _ie_, than you have other approaches to consider.

Comment: @ZorgoZ according to the grammar rules of Papiamento, the last letter (the 'e') gets removed and the suffix "iendo" is appended to it.

Comment: You want to create a regex with all those 16.000 words? It would be anything but effective. Why not trying to get the infinitive form from the original? You just have two endings to check - and use the rule from your comment to find the match in the array.

Comment: @ZorgoZ yeah, thank you for your help, I also had someone else that told me something similar, I’ll take that into consideration and consider approaching it some other way.

Comment: Maybe an indexing solution? split words into groups based on starting characters or something? then have a more limited scope of strings to have to validate each time? still seems inefficient.

Comment: What is the final result? `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a database including all infinitive verbs (indexed column).
If there is no exception in the language (understand: you always only remove the last letter to get the root), then the infinite form is enough. Otherwise in the database you will need another column to define the root of the word. Alternative : use root form as key. Add all usefull conjugated forms in new columns if there are language exceptions.

By using a simple regex that detects infinitives and other conjugated forms, you can check for each match that it is really a verb and not a false positive.

"Comiendo" will be a false positive since no verb in the database will have this key.

```
/(\w*ndo\b|\w*a\b|\w*i\b|\w*e\b)/gm
```

[image: Matching example]
Considering the volume of words to know, it is true that it is not a good choice to use all of them in the regex, but rather to use a database to validate in a second time, it is done for that I think: a simple select will be fast on a very large volume of data.

```
        var wordsFinder = new Regex(@"(\w*ndo\b|\w*a\b|\w*i\b|\w*e\b)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (Match match in wordsFinder.Matches(inputText))
        {
            var word = match.Value.ToLower();
            string infinitiveForm = null;
            if (word.EndsWith("iendo"))
                infinitiveForm = $"{word.Substring(0, word.Length - "iendo".Length)}e"; // not tested, please adapt :)
            else if (word.EndsWith("ando"))
                infinitiveForm = $"{word.Substring(0, word.Length - "ando".Length)}a";
            else
                infinitiveForm = word;

            // now check for infinitiveForm in the database
        }
```